# scipy.io : element.item(0) vs element[0]

Tags: python, matlab, scipy

I would like to know the difference between:

```
element.item(0)
```

and

```
element[0]
```

after converting a matlab file to a "dictionary-like" structure using scipy.io

Thank you.

Comment: What is `element`? Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Did you use `io.loadmat` to load the file?  So the result is a dictionary containing, among other things, variables which are `numpy` arrays.  Depending on the complexity of the source MATLAB those arrays may be nested levels of object dtype arrays, with single elements or shapes like (1,1).  `item` is one way of extracting elements from such arrays; so is indexing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your `element` is a `numpy` array.

Then `element.item(k)` according to [this documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.item.html) is `k-th` element in flattened version of `element` array.

While `element[k]` is `k-th` sub-array of `element`.

In case if your `element` array is 1-dimensional they both mean the same.

If it is multi-dimensional (N-dimensional) then they mean different things, first is just single element (number/scalar) (`k-th` element inside flattened array version), second is sub-array of (N-1) dimensions (at index `k` of `0-th` dimension).

Comment: Thank you a lot! This is exactly what I was looking for.